# SQL And Northwind

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, northwind

I have a query where i can find all the products, all the customers that bought each product and the quantity.

```
select OD.ProductID, OD.Quantity, O.CustomerID
from dbo.[Order Details] OD inner join dbo.Orders O on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
Order by OD.ProductID ASC, OD.Quantity DESC
```

But what i need is to now which customer bought the most of each product. How can I do it?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? In later versions you can use RANK() to work this out

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `top 1 with ties` with `rank` window function:

```
select top 1 with ties OD.ProductID,
    OD.Quantity,
    O.CustomerID
from dbo.[Order Details] OD
inner join dbo.Orders O on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
order by rank() over (
        partition by OD.ProductID order by OD.Quantity desc
        );
```

The above will return multiple rows per productId if there are multiple customers with max quantity ordered for that product.

If you want to get only one row, you can use `row_number`:

```
select top 1 with ties OD.ProductID,
    OD.Quantity,
    O.CustomerID
from dbo.[Order Details] OD
inner join dbo.Orders O on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
order by row_number() over (
        partition by OD.ProductID order by OD.Quantity desc
        );
```

You can also do this without `top`:

```
select *
from (
    select OD.ProductID,
        OD.Quantity,
        O.CustomerID,
        row_number() over (
            partition by OD.ProductID order by OD.Quantity desc
            ) as rn
    from dbo.[Order Details] OD
    inner join dbo.Orders O on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Is there a way i can do it with subquery? I have never used rank or with ties

Comment: @WaltherEmilioCarrasco - Window functions work great for these kind of problems. If you don't want to use `top`, see the third query in the updated answer.

Comment: You should take this opportunity to learn to use window functions.